# Select2 will no longer show in Visual force

Tags: visualforce

I had the select2 Drop down working yesterday. I saved my data locally and we did a sandbox refresh last night and imported all of our contacts which this drop down will work with. I put the code in and ran it today and the drop down no longer appears. I thought it was the increased amount of contacts. However, I tried with the sampleArray and it still does not show up. I checked the HTML and it is reading in the contacts like it should. Any ideas?

My /head

```
<head>
    <!-- stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.css"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
        padding: 40px;
        }
    </style>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.1/select2.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        var nameArray = [];
        var count = 0;
        var sampleArray = [{id:0,text:'enhancement'}, {id:1,text:'bug'}
                           ,{id:2,text:'duplicate'},{id:3,text:'invalid'}
                           ,{id:4,text:'wontfix'}];
        <apex:repeat value="{!nameBirth}" var="nB">
            nameArray.push({id:count,text:'{!nB}'});
            count++;
        </apex:repeat>

        $("#selStudent").select2({ data: nameArray, placeholder: "Student"});

    });
    </script>

</head>
```

Where the select2 gets placed

```
<div class="col-lg-4" align="center">
            <h4>Select Student</h4>
            <input type="hidden" id="selStudent" style="width:300px"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: The same code is working for me;

Comment: Do check for errors in console.

Comment: No errors as far as I can tell. When I remove the <Apex:repeat> section it shows up fine, but no data of course. I checked the HTML of the page, with apex:repeat and the value for selStudent, is very large compared to to using the sample data. The box also does not get created. Does Select 2 have a maximum input size?

Comment: No, there is no options limit;

Comment: It's working fine for even 1,000 option;

Comment: Wait, I found it. Some of the strings getting pulled in have ' in them. So the formatting is wrong. I'm changing that to see if it works after that.

Comment: After Changing a few names that fixed it. Thank you for you help.

Answer (score -1):

The code worked fine. Some of the Strings being imported had ' in them. This caused the script to crash. Added JSENCODE to fix the issue.

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        var nameArray = [];
        var count = 0;
        <apex:repeat value="{!nameBirth}" var="nB">
            nameArray.push({id:count,text:'{!JSENCODE(nB)}'});
        count++;
        </apex:repeat>

        $("#selStudent").select2({ 
            data: nameArray, 
            placeholder: "Student",

        });


    });

    </script>
```

Comment: That's why you should `JSENCODE` any inputs before using them in a script.